# Let $(X, d)$ a metric space. Show that $\tau_{c} \subseteq \tau_{d}$, where $ \tau_{c} $ is the cofinite topology on $ X $

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, d)$ a metric space. Show that $\tau_{c} \subseteq \tau_{d}$, where $ \tau_{c} $ is the cofinite topology on $ X $.

Let $ A\in \tau_{c} $. Then, $ X\setminus A $ is finite or $ A = \emptyset$. If $ A = \emptyset$, then $ A \in \tau_{d}$. If $ X \setminus A$ is finite, then,

and here I do not know how to continue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finite set is closed in the metric space. So $X-A$ is metric closed, so $A$ is metric open.

Comment: $X \setminus A$ is finite in $\tau_{c}$ so is closed in $\tau_{c}$, how can I deduce that $X \setminus A$ is closed in $\tau_{d}$?

Comment: $X-A$ is finite, this is a property related to set only, no topology is involved. Now I prove that it is closed in the metric space. It suffices to prove for one point set, say, $X-A=\{a\}$. For any $x\in\{a\}^{c}$, choose $B_{\delta}(x)$, where $\delta=2^{-1}d(x,a)$, then $B\subseteq\{a\}^{c}$, so $\{a\}^{c}$ is metric open, hence $\{a\}$ is metric closed.

Comment: I understand, but I think I need to ensure that the complement it is closed in the topology, not in a metric space, since that´s what It needs to be proved

Comment: I don't quite follow. Now you have chosen $A\in\tau_{c}$ and wish to show that $A\in\tau_{d}$. If $A=\emptyset$, you have concluded that $A\in\tau_{d}$. Now we deal with $A\ne\emptyset$, this amounts only to the case that $X-A$ is a finite set. Since I have shown that $X-A$ is metric closed, this is my terminology, it should be said as $\tau_{d}$-closed, so $X-(X-A)=A$ is then $\tau_{d}$-open, in other words, $A\in\tau_{d}$.